# Position of dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to position a dropdown menu below the list item that activates it. Right now each dropdown menu is placed independently.

```css
ul{
 display:inline-block;
 list-style:none;
 text-align:center;
 width: 100%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

ul li
{
 display:inline;
 padding:10px;
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
}

#listaUgn
{
 display:block;
 position:absolute;
}

#listaUgn li
{
 display:block;
 padding:10px;
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
 max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="izborSrednji">
  <ul id="listaSrednja">
    <li class="izborLinije"><a href="">Programiranje I</a></li>
    <li class="izborLinije"><a href="">WRD</a></li>
    <li class="izborLinije"  >Klikni za jos
      <ul id="listaUgn" >
        <li class="izborLinijeUg"><a href="">Programiranje I</a></li>
        <li class="izborLinijeUg"><a href="">WRD</a></li>
        <li class="izborLinijeUg">PSR</li>
        <li class="izborLinijeUg">SP</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="izborLinije">SP</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's better if u made some plunker for this type of questions. It makes easy to solve your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `position: relative` to the dropdown element's parent, then the dropdown will be positioned absolutely, relative to it's parent element.

For example:

```css
ul{
 display:inline-block;
 list-style:none;
 text-align:center;
 width: 100%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

ul li
{
 display:inline;
 padding:10px;
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
  position: relative;
}

ul li:hover #listaUgn {
  display: block;
}

#listaUgn
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#listaUgn li
{
 display:block;
 padding:10px;
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
 max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="izborSrednji">
  <ul id="listaSrednja">
    <li class="izborLinije"><a href="">Programiranje I</a></li>
    <li class="izborLinije"><a href="">WRD</a></li>
    <li class="izborLinije"  >Klikni za jos
      <ul id="listaUgn" >
        <li class="izborLinijeUg"><a href="">Programiranje I</a></li>
        <li class="izborLinijeUg"><a href="">WRD</a></li>
        <li class="izborLinijeUg">PSR</li>
        <li class="izborLinijeUg">SP</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="izborLinije">SP</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

this site can be a good reference for you: https://css-tricks.com/targetting-menu-elements-submenus-navigation-bar/

**Update**:

```css
nav {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  background: #111;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.8em 1.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80%;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 1px -1px -1px 1px #000, -1px 1px -1px 1px #fff, 0 0 6px 3px #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.nav li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav>li {
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 4px #aaa solid;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.nav>li>a {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 2em .33em -0.5em #555;
}

.nav>li:hover,
.nav>li:hover>a {
  border-bottom-color: orange;
}

.nav li:hover>a {
  color: orange;
}

.nav>li:first-child {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.nav>li:first-child>a {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
}

.nav>li:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.nav>li:last-child>a {
  border-radius: 0 4px 0 0;
}

.nav li li a {
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.nav li a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  top: 50%;
  right: 5px;
}


/* submenu positioning*/

.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-bottom: 5px solid orange;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -99999em;
}

.nav>li:hover>ul {
  left: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.nav>li li:hover>ul {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  top: -1px;
}


/* arrow hover styling */

.nav>li>a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border-top-color: #aaa;
}

.nav>li:hover>a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: orange;
  margin-top: -5px
}

.nav li li>a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border-left-color: #aaa;
  margin-top: -5px
}

.nav li li:hover>a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: orange;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Resume</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item a lonng submenu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Ray</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Veronica</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bushy</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Havoc</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Download</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rants</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So sorry about that, I forgot to add the code snippet. And I have updated it just now. Thanks for the input